# how can i put mime type in tags in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I need to build my application with the MIME type defined in importation tags.
I'm using Vue, and when I build the applications, I need the generated tags to look like this:

```html
<link type="text/css" href="/qa/css/chunk-54f18ebe.31dd6a2b.css" rel="prefetch">
<link type="text/javascript" href="/qa/js/chunk-2d0be08c.b60942c3.js" rel="prefetch">
```

But the Vue build generates this:

```html
<link href="/qa/css/chunk-54f18ebe.31dd6a2b.css" rel="prefetch">
<link href="/qa/js/chunk-2d0be08c.b60942c3.js" rel="prefetch">
```

I have a need to apply this solution because I use the `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` header.

The `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` header is a security measure that prevents the browser from attempting to detect the MIME type of a download automatically, as this behavior can be exploited for certain kinds of attacks. The browser will block requests for stylesheets and scripts which are not delivered with a CSS or Javascript MIME type, respectively.

My company has a policy of security and IT obligatory need to put the `nosniff` in a header. How can I fix this problem when I build my application?

Answer (score 0):

As of Vue CLI 4.5.3, there's no built-in way to do this, so you'll have to either post-process the built HTML files, or patch the build libraries to correctly insert the MIME types. Here's how to do the latter:

1. Edit `public/index.html` to insert the MIME types for any links there (the default Vue CLI generated project includes a MIME-less `<link>` for `favicon.ico`).
2. Patch two build libraries that insert `<link>`s for JS/CSS:

   - `@vue/preload-webpack-plugin@1.1.2`

     ```js
      // node_modules/@vue/preload-webpack-plugin/src/index.js
     +const mimeTypes = require('mime-types')   // line 22

      class PreloadPlugin {
        generateLinks (compilation, htmlPluginData) {
          //...

          for (const file of sortedFilteredFiles) {
            const href = `${publicPath}${file}`

            const attributes = {
              href,
              rel: options.rel
            }
     +                                          // line 74
     +      const type = mimeTypes.lookup(file)
     +      if (type) {
     +        attributes.type = type
     +      }

            //...
          }
        }
      }
     ```
   - `html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0`

     ```js
      // node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/index.js
      class HtmlWebpackPlugin {
        generateHtmlTags (assets) {
          //...

          const styles = assets.css.map(stylePath => ({
            tagName: 'link',
            selfClosingTag: selfClosingTag,
            voidTag: true,
            attributes: {
     +        type: 'text/css',                 // line 527
              href: stylePath,
              rel: 'stylesheet'
            }
          }));

          //...

          if (assets.favicon) {
            head.push({
              tagName: 'link',
              selfClosingTag: selfClosingTag,
              voidTag: true,
              attributes: {
     +          type: 'image/x-icon',           // line 542
                rel: 'shortcut icon',
                href: assets.favicon
              }
            });
          }

          //...
        }
      }
     ```

You could then use [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to automatically patch those libraries upon `npm install`.